# jQuery toggleClass if div hasClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I am trying to toggle an .active class on a slider on my page to create some pagination.

I'm currently using :

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if (jQuery('#image1').hasClass('crsl-active')){
        jQuery(".pager1").toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

When my slider goes to the second div the .crsl-active class goes to the next div but the .active class on the .pager1 isn't removed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are only checking it on page load

Answer (score 1):

First remove all "active" and then apply your rule(s):

```
$('.active').each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('active');
});

    if (jQuery('#image1').hasClass('crsl-active')){
        jQuery(".pager1").toggleClass("active");
    }
```

first rule can be written as:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

but personally I don't like too much.

Comment: `but personally I don't like too much` - Why?

Comment: why use an each loop when the syntax which you 'don't like too much' is better

Comment: When you want to remove a class maybe you need also to do something else with selected node, so at develop time I prefer an "each" to write extra instructions later (Ex: alert to fast debug without log). It's not possible everytime concatenate all instructions needed, however before deploy it's a good optimization.